# Go: How to use named arguments when calling a function?

Tags: go

How can I invoke a function while using named arguments?

(If it's unclear what named arguments are, here's an example of [using them in Python](https://treyhunner.com/2018/04/keyword-arguments-in-python/))

Example of what I'd like to do:

```
func Add(a int, b int) int {
  return a + b
}

func main() {
  c := Add(a: 1, b:3)
  return c
}
```

However, the above gives me the error:

```
unexpected :, expecting comma or )
```

(it's referring to the ':' right after the 'a')

Comment: Go does not have named arguments. You can use structs as a workaround.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame

Comment: Is it? Wanting a programming language to behave like `insertFavouriteProgrammingLanguageHere` tends to lead people to treat it like said language. Go is different from Python. For a reason. Embrace it.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg what sort of behavior would you expect to a Go programmer to embrace in this scenario? And what benefit would you expect it to confer?

Comment: Plain and simple: Try not to use idioms from other programming languages. `c := Add(1,3)` or `c :=Add(a,b)` do just fine. And for example, what would be the output of `a:=1;b:=2;c:=Add(a:3,b:4);fmt.Println(a,b,c)`. Not quite obvious - and something not obvious and/or making assumptions is less desired, isn't it? It gets even worse when `Add := func(a,b float) float`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go does not have named arguments.  The closest thing I know of in Go to named arguments is using a struct as input.  So for your example you could do -

```
type Input struct {
  A int
  B int
}

func Add(in Input) int {
  return in.A + in.B
}

func main() {
  c := Add(Input{A: 1, B: 3})
  return c
}
```

Comment: Also allows for optional arguments.  Ie you don't need to provide filed values if you want "zero".

Answer (score 3):

In brief: the Go language does not support named args but IDEs do (see below).

I agree that named arguments could be useful in Go.  It could help avoid bugs.  For example, just yesterday my tests picked up a bug where the source and dest. parameters to copy() (Go built-in function) were back to front.

However, there are probably hundreds of useful language features that Go *could* have. We try to avoid adding non-essential features to the language to keep things simple.  Once you've used Go for a large project you will greatly appreciate how much simpler things are compared to other languages. (I have used more than a dozen languages professionally and Go is by far the least annoying.)

But actually you **can** have named arguments if your IDE supports it. For example, I use GoLand and when you enter the arguments to a function it shows the parameter name (in light gray) in-line with a colon before the value.  This is even better than what you are used to as you don't even have to type the name!